# Ajax call not working in my ubuntu with xamp?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Controller:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('form-view');
}
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

my view:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
  // set an on click on the button
  $("#button").click(function () {
    // get the time if clicked via an ajax get query
    // see the code in the controller time.php
    alert("hi");
    $.get("/index.php/getTime", function (time) {
      // update the textarea with the time
      alert("hello);
      $("#text").html("Time on the server is:" + time);
    });
  });
});
```

it's not calling my controller time.php ?

In my time .php index method I am just print the "echo time();" only.

Can anybody help me? I want to call that controller and it will return the time value of server in my textarea

Comment: I do not see any Ajax code what so ever. Please ad the code where ajax click on the edit button to re edit question bit unclear

Comment: _`ubuntu with xampp`_? Are you sure its a XAMPP
?

Comment: What is the error ? Not working is not a valid issue description.

Comment: add necessary code for ajax also.

Comment: WHere is the ajax code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.get("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/getTime", function (time) {
  // update the textarea with the time
  alert("hello");
  $("#text").html("Time on the server is:" + time);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try to make the function and run ajax onclick event like this


<script>

    function deleteDomain()
    {

        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('Test/deleteDomain');?>/",
            success:function(data)
            {

            alert(data);

            }

            });
        }

</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteDomain()"  title="Delete" class="icon-2 info-tooltip">Delete</a>
```

For more how to call ajax request in codeigniter try this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

your ajax calling is wrong change it to:

```
$.get("welcome/yourfunctionName", function (time) {
      // update the textarea with the time
      alert("hello");
      $("#text").html("Time on the server is:" + time);
    });
```